# cancel application installation in the middle of installing

Tags: android, events, installation

I am trying to create an application which is for block another pre-defined application list(let's say malware applications). For that I thought of creating a periodically running background service which is checking for application which installing at the moment of checking and get the package name and cancel the event. Anyway I couldn't find any resources which do similar thing. Is that possible to do? If possible, could you shed some light on this?

Comment: connection blocking while installing is not a good solution. application will install after downloading. then we should block the downloading.right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible to do? If possible, could you shed some light on
>   this?

AFAIK, This is not possible.